# Model name conflict while Extending Django Oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm trying to extend an Oscar app so I forked it. Now following [this example](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_customise_models.html#example) line and line trying to add a field to the `ProductImage` Model class.

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProductImage    
class ProductImage(AbstractProductImage):
        thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/thumbnails/')
from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

on `runserver` I get the error

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'productimage' models in application 
'catalogue': <class 'oscar.apps.catalogue.models.ProductImage'> 
and <class 'forked_apps.catalogue.models.ProductImage'>.
```

I know if I change the Name of class `ProductImage` to something else this will work but why in the example do they use the same name then ? Also in future suppose I want to fork any app I would like to add fields to the existing class only not to a new class. Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: Since you forked the project, you are ready to change any code in it. There is no need to treat it as immutable framework, and only inherit from base classes. Just modify the source code of ProductImage.

Comment: What if I want to add a field to an existing model. I don't want to make a new model for I will have to do data migration. Can't I just extend the existing model or that is not possible?

Comment: The new field has to be stored in the database table, so migration is inevitable, whether you make a new model or not. Unless the field can be computed from other fields, and need no storage.

Comment: Field migration I understand. Suppose currently `Product` model has all my objects. Now I want to add a field to `Product` model how do I go about it ? If I name my extended class as `Product` it will throw an error. If I change the name to say `NewProduct` I will lose all the data of `Product` class ? Do you get what I am saying ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you remove `oscar.apps.catalogue` from the list of `INSTALLED_APPS` when you replace it with your own override. In particular if you call [`get_core_apps()`](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/customisation.html#replace-oscar-s-app-with-your-own-in-installed-apps), make sure you include `forked_apps.catalogue` in the list you provide to the function.

Failing to do so may cause Django to load Oscar's models before loading your overrides which would result in duplicates (and the error).

Comment: Thanks patrys. Can you answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268262/newly-added-fields-not-showing-in-profile-edit-form-in-django-oscar

Answer (score 0):

If I don't import anything from `oscar.apps.catalogue.models` then those models are not registered and hence I won't see a conflict. I was importing a model(not shown in the question) from it thus I had a conflict.

Comment: Buried in their documentation is the caution that e.g. `from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *` should be done *after* defining your overrides.