# Newly added fields not showing in Profile Edit form in Django Oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I want to extend the User model. I followed the steps mentioned in [this doc](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/use_a_custom_user_model.html). I made a new app `extended_user` whose models.py reads as :

```
from django.db import models

from oscar.apps.customer.abstract_models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class User(AbstractUser):

    nickname =  models.CharField(_("nick_name"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.last_name.upper(), self.first_name)
        return full_name.strip()
```

In settings.py I mention

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "extended_user.User"
```

I make and run migrations. In profile view I can see `nickname` field but in Profile Edit view I don't. What do I have to do to see the newly added field in the Profile Edit form ?

Comment: Are you using the Django Model Form or your form is hardcoded with fields declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you do not use a separate rofile class. In that case Oscar [sets](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/releases/1.1/src/oscar/apps/customer/forms.py#L361) `ProfileForm` to point to the [`UserForm`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/releases/1.1/src/oscar/apps/customer/forms.py#L262-L288) class.

That class in turn has a more-or-less hardcoded list of `fields`. (In reality it says ["whichever fields exist out of this list"](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/releases/1.1/src/oscar/core/compat.py#L55-L71).)

The easiest way to go forward from here is to [override](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/customisation.html#start-customising) `customer.forms.ProfileForm` with your own class that uses your newly defined `User` model and the list of fields that better suits your usecase. (Create a `your_app.customer.forms` module and define a `ProfileForm` inside.)

Comment: I added the new field in the hardcoded list and it worked. But is it a good practice to edit Oscar source code or Overriding the form is a better approach ?

Comment: Overriding it in your project makes it possible to upgrade Oscar and saves you from having to distribute your own builds of Oscar for the time you decide to deploy your code to production (by default `pip` will install an unmodified version of Oscar and break your site).

Comment: I added a `forms.py` (which has `ProfileForm` class inside it) inside my_app/customer. But the overriding is not working ? Some other changes I have to make

Comment: You will also need to tell Oscar that you're replacing its `customer` app. Pass yours to `get_core_apps()`.

Comment: So customer app also I need to fork ? i did that its working.

Comment: any thoughts about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248923/django-oscar-site-serving-multiple-geographies

Answer (score 0):

1. `python3 manage.py oscar_fork_app customer`
2. add your app on your settings :

```
from oscar import get_core_apps

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'YOUR_APP',
] + get_core_apps(['customer'])
```

3. The last part is to put this content of `customer/forms.py`:

   - it changes the Model with yours to access new added fields;
   - extends existing UserForm to keep all clean data;
   - change `ProfileForm` var as Oscar use it for render form of profile to point to your new form.

```
from oscar.apps.customer.forms import UserForm as CoreUserForm
from user.models import User
from django import forms

from oscar.core.compat import existing_user_fields

class UserForm(CoreUserForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = existing_user_fields(['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'])

ProfileForm = UserForm
```